# Crystal Report Hangs/Freezed when Loading

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, windows-services

​Hi Everyone,
Currently i'm having trouble to solve an issue which caused Crystal Reports hang when loading process. Below are the scenario:
1. Basically, i've built an windows service to export Crystal report to PDF simultaneously
2. But some times when the service export the reports until certain limit, the service will suddenly Hang, meaning Crystal Report suddenly stuck in the middle of ReportDocument.Load() function, which caused i need to restart the service in order to let the service be able to load the report again.

I believed that i've put all the necessary codes to release/free memory resources which attached to the report object when the report is exported, such as:
1. reportDocument.Close();

2. reportDocument.Dispose();
3. GC.Collect();
   But still, the issue has not been solved yet. I've did a lot of research and found that actually this problem is somehow related to the PrintJobLimit configuration,  but before i change the configuration, i would like to know:
4. Is there any way except than increasing the print job limit can solve this issue ?
5. If increasing the print job limit is the only option, can anyone explain to me how does the print job limit works ? Is one page of report considered as 1 print job ? If that's the case, then why i can still be able to export a report that contains 100 more pages without any issue while my print job limit is 75?

Any advice from you will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone faced the issue i mentioned above, can refer to below links, i've asked the SAP people, and i think they have a good answer about this.

https://answers.sap.com/questions/702435/crystal-report-hang-when-load-report.html